# About the use of Young and Hölder inequalities

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

In the following Terraneo's paper [Terr](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.2483&rep=rep1&type=pdf) we have an idea of the proof for a certain Cauchy semilinear problem (theorem 3, page 5) but I'm stuck in one important detail in [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.2483&rep=rep1&type=pdf). How are they used the Young and Hölder inequalities in the third line of inequalities on page 6? I know the fact that $\lVert G_t\rVert_{L^r}=ct^{(\frac{N(1-r)}{2r})}$ and $e^{t\Delta}u=G_t\ast u$, where $G_t$ is the gaussian function associated with the heat kernel, but I worried about the next fact pointed in the paper

$$\lVert u^{\alpha+1}\rVert_{L^p}\leq \lVert u\rVert_{L^p}^{\alpha+1}$$

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am getting you right. You want to know why the inequality

$$\left\| \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta} |u|^\alpha u(s) ~ds \right\|_p \leq C \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\tfrac{n \alpha}{2p}} s^{-\sigma(\alpha+1)} (s^\sigma \|u\|_p )^{\alpha+1} ~ds$$

holds?

- First notice that $\|e^{\tau \Delta} v \|_p \leq (4\pi \tau)^{-n/(2r)} \|v\|_q$ for $p > q$; where $\tfrac{1}{r}=\tfrac{1}{q}-\tfrac{1}{p}$. Hence we have
  $$\|e^{(t-s) \Delta} |u|^\alpha u(s) \|_p \leq C (t-s)^{-n/(2r)} \||u|^\alpha u(s)\|_q$$
  and setting $q=\tfrac{p}{\alpha+1}$ yields $r=\tfrac{p}{\alpha}$ and thus
  $$\|e^{(t-s) \Delta} |u|^\alpha u(s) \|_p \leq C (t-s)^{-\tfrac{n\alpha}{2p}} \||u|^\alpha u(s)\|_{p/(\alpha+1)} \tag{1}.$$
- Second notice that we have $\tfrac{\alpha+1}{p}=\tfrac{\alpha}{p}+\tfrac{1}{p}$ and thus by Hölder's inequality
  $$\||u|^\alpha u(s)\|_{p/(\alpha+1)} \leq \| |u|^\alpha\|_{p/\alpha} \|u(s)\|_p=\|u(s)\|_{p}^\alpha \|u(s)\|_p=\|u(s)\|_{p}^{\alpha+1} \tag{2} $$

Now, starting from the beginning, take the $L^p$-norm into the integral, do (1) and then (2).

---

EDIT: By applying [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) to $\|e^{\tau \Delta} v \|_p$ we have

$$\|e^{\tau \Delta} v \|_p=\|G_\tau *v \|_p \leq \|G_\tau\|_s \|v\|_q$$
for $\tfrac{1}{s}=1+\tfrac{1}{p}-\tfrac{1}{q}$. Notice that $\|G_{\tau/s}\|_1=1$ and hence

$$\| G_\tau \|_s = \left( (4\pi \tau)^{-sn/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-s |x|^2/(4\tau)} ~dx \right)^{1/s}=(4\pi \tau)^{-n/2} (4\pi \tfrac{\tau}{s})^{n/(2s)}\leq (4\pi \tau)^{-n(s-1)/(2s)}$$

and setting yields $\tfrac{1}{r}:=-\tfrac{1}{s}+1=\tfrac{s-1}{s}$ yields finally for $\tfrac{1}{r}=\tfrac{1}{q}-\tfrac{1}{p}$

$$\| G_\tau \|_s \leq (4\pi \tau)^{-n(s-1)/(2s)}=(4\pi \tau)^{-n/(2r)}.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I have only one question. When you say: 'First notice that...' I suppose you are using a kinf of Young inequality, but the inequality you wrote doesn't see as the usual Young. Could you explain me how to get that inequality you wrote? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @DiegoVargas This is Young's convolution inequality and not the classical one. The key is that one can write $e^{\tau \Delta} v$ as a convolution of the Gaussian with $v$; as you already noticed. You can find a proof in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answers @MarvinF